# Using socket.io AND angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, socket.io

I'm developing a socket.io compatible project (this means: the client library is socket.io, and the server is implemented in python, instead of nodejs).

Socket.io is based on jQuery.

Is it safe to use socket.io in Angular, considering Angular ships with an internal "jqLite"? Is it enough for socket.io?

Is it safe, regarding Angular, if I include a jQuery version? will it cause -an official jquery- unexpected behaviors on Angular -assume I use, at most, Angular and ngRoute-, or will it be fully compatible?

I'm a n00b at angular internals and socket.io :$

Comment: Socket.io is not based on jQuery. Socket.io does not have any relation/dependency to jQuery.

Comment: Seems I misread the samples sources :s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't cause problems.

You just need to make sure you load jquery before angular, if jquery is loaded angular uses the loaded full jquery instead of jqlite. It's supported and should not cause any problems.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Cool! Did not know jqLite was just a fallback. I thought it was mandatory and non-compatible :p.